# Ubuntu 17.04 - Installing a python library (xgboost) breaks software updater

Tags: ubuntu, python

I'm having a weird issue when I install a python library, xgboost, this breaks the update manager.

```
cd && mkdir xgboost_install && cd xgboost_install && sudo git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost && cd xgboost && sudo make -j4 && cd python-package && sudo python3.6 setup.py install
```

This creates a folder called xgboost_install, and clones the xgboost repo, and build and installs the xgboost python module.

However, this breaks the software updater if you tried to use the software updater after the installation.

---

Full script:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install python3.6
sudo apt-get -y install g++
sudo apt-get -y install libfreetype6-dev
sudo apt-get -y install python3.6-dev
curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3.6
sudo pip3.6 install -U matplotlib
sudo pip3.6 install -U numpy
sudo pip3.6 install -U scipy
sudo pip3.6 install -U pandas
sudo pip3.6 install -U scikit-learn
sudo pip3.6 install -U lightgbm
sudo pip3.6 install -U plotly
sudo pip3.6 install -U jupyter
sudo pip3.6 install -U seaborn
sudo pip3.5 install -U keras
sudo pip3.6 install -U tensorflow
sudo pip3.6 install -U nltk
sudo pip3.6 install -U pillow
sudo pip3.6 install -U TFLearn
sudo pip3.6 install -U nose
sudo pip3.6 install -U coveralls
sudo apt-get -y install git
sudo pip3.6 install http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-0.1.12.post2-cp36-cp36m-linux_x86_64.whl 
sudo pip3.6 install -U torchvision
cd && mkdir xgboost_install && cd xgboost_install && sudo git clone --recursive https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost && cd xgboost && sudo make -j4 && cd python-package && sudo python3.6 setup.py install
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't sudo install pip packages. Try running the installation within a Python virtual env or a conda env. And without the sudo. This should work.

Comment: Guess that's my only way. I went and check log files, and there are python libraries that got updated, and some or all parts of the software updater uses python libraries that got updated too.